# Why do I get "Error in check.data(data, allow.levels = TRUE)" when using predict in bnlearn

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

The training data:

[image]

With R I need to then make 2 predictions (Buy Computer: YES/NO) based on these features
[image]

Essentially to say whether it would be Yes or No for each of the two.
I've tried the code below and get the error

> Error in check.data(data, allow.levels = TRUE) : the data are missing.

```
> library(bnlearn)
> 
> data_computer <- data.frame(predictions.table)
> data_computer$Income <- as.factor(data_computer$Income)
> data_computer$Student <- as.factor(data_computer$Student)
> data_computer$Credit.Rating <- as.factor(data_computer$Credit.Rating)
> data_computer$Buy.Computer <- as.factor(data_computer$Buy.Computer)
> 
> network_structure <- empty.graph(nodes = c("Income","Student","Credit.Rating","Buy.Computer"))
> 
> network_structure <- set.arc(network_structure,"Income","Buy.Computer")
> network_structure <- set.arc(network_structure,"Student","Buy.Computer")
> network_structure <- set.arc(network_structure,"Credit.Rating","Buy.Computer")
> 
> learned.network <- bn.fit(network_structure, data_computer)
> 
> data_computer_test <- data.frame(
+     Income = c("High", "Low"),
+     Student = c("FALSE", "FALSE"),
+     Credit.Rating = c("Fair", "Excellent")
+ )
> 
> data_computer_test$Income <- as.factor(data_computer_test$Income)
> data_computer_test$Student <- as.factor(data_computer_test$Student)
> data_computer_test$Credit.Rating <- as.factor(data_computer_test$Credit.Rating)
> 
> new_predictions <- predict(learned.network, newdata=data_computer_test, node="Buy.Computer", method="bayes-lw")
```

> Error in check.data(data, allow.levels = TRUE) : the data are missing.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Naim Assis Ismail! What other packages are you using? I cannot find `check.data`, is it not in `bnlearn` afaict. Also, please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: agree with all of the above, except `check.data` which is an unexported function from `bnlearn`. But this is a typo by using `newdata` argument instead of `data`

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for `predict()` ([link](https://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/predict.and.impute.html)):

```
Usage
## S3 method for class 'bn.fit'
predict(object, node, data, cluster, method = "parents", ...,
  prob = FALSE, debug = FALSE)
```

The minimum required arguments are `object`, `node`, and `data`.  (`cluster` is optional, and `method`, `prob` and `debug` have default values)

Your code:

```
new_predictions <- predict(learned.network, newdata=data_computer_test, node="Buy.Computer", method="bayes-lw")
```

R will correctly assume that the unnamed first argument is the `object`.
All the others are named so will be assigned to arguments with matching names.
There is no expected argument named `newdata` so this is passed to the `...` and you are left with no `data`, hence the error message.

Try this:

```
new_predictions <- predict(
    object = learned.network, 
    data = data_computer_test, 
    node = "Buy.Computer", 
    method = "bayes-lw")
```